# Mule ESB CloudHub No listener found for request and Available listeners are

Tags: http, logging, mule, mule-esb, cloudhub

Multiple applications are deployed to Mule CloudHub and their logs are being cluttered/spammed with someone attempting to send some sort of request:

```
No listener found for request: (GET)/


No listener found for request: (POST)/azenv.php


No listener found for request: (HEAD)/robots.txt


No listener found for request: (GET)/manager/html
```

as an example, and:

```
Available listeners are: [listed available API endpoints, won't expose them here]
```

Due to application logs being limited to a certain amount of MB and time, these *spammy* logs are cluttering and pushing back important ones.

The listener is using the HTTP protocol.

Ways of dealing with that, that I know of, are setting up a VPC and/or at least use HTTPS with TSL/SSL. What are other options other than VPC and HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is just switching the log level of the class triggering those logs to a "higher" level. That information should be available in the full log entries but I believe the class is `org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry` and a WARN level should do.

Comment: Yes, that takes care of that! But takes care of other logs from the class as well, for example, _method not allowed_. Is it possible in log4j2 to specify which logs to ignore or filter them out from the class?